# laravel routing not working nginx server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, routes

I installed nginx server. I have a laravel5.5 testing project. when I hit http://localhost/my_project/public it works perfectly. But when I do routing for http://localhost/my_project/public/about it shows 404 not found.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the nginx section in the link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#pretty-urls. Is it similar to the one in your nginx conf ?

Comment: I tried with that but didn't work. thanks

Comment: please add your nginx config to the question

Comment: @FatemehMajd, I found out the solution. please the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution for laravel routing problem in nginx server without creating virtual host. solution is in below.

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
2. configuration for sub directory in below.

   ```
   location ^~ /sub_directory {

           alias /var/www/html/sub_directory/public;
           try_files $uri $uri/ @sub_directory;

           location ~ \.php {
                   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/sub_directory/public/index.php;
           }
   }

   location @sub_directory {
           rewrite /sub_directory/(.*)$ /sub_directory/index.php?/$1 last;
   }
   ```